# What does Google Earth Engine's image.unmix() differentiate from other implementations?

Tags: remote-sensing, google-earth-engine

I want to realize a project with spectrally unmixed Landsat imagery. However, I find no satisfying information on [the respective GEE function, *image.unmix()*](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_transforms).

I processed a few scenes with the exact same three endmembers both in GEE and with the help of [RSToolbox package's *mesma()* function](http://jxsw.de/2018/03/15/spectral-unmixing-in-R.html) in R. The results differ largely, with mesma() looking quite more promising.
I cannot compare to the widely used ENVI function right now, but it seems that there is strong differences in implementations.

I am not even sure if they all three could classify as *Multiple Endmember Spectral Mixture Analysis* (MESMA) or if I'm comparing apples with oranges here.

The GEE help file linked at the top quotes:

> For more flexible methods, see the [Array Transformations page](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/arrays_transformations)

I fear, I don't quite understand what Array Transformations are capable of and how they are used. How would I build my own unmix() with these and would it enhance my results?

Can anybody could shed light on potential differences and the exact functionality of the GEE implementation?

Comment: Look in the help forum for explanations of developers

Comment: I am processing unmix() in GEE and I have the same question as you did. Did you find any answer yet? I would really appreciate it if you could share any information about this issue. Best,
Linke

Comment: Because I could not find any details on the GEE implementation I finally proceeded with R. This led me to be able to run smaller scale tests and variations, but I never did a comparison with GEE since.

Comment: @77hz Could you please share your R code? I have the task as you did. I would really appreciate it if you could share any information regarding this issue.

Comment: @Mbariz I don't have a clean code with it ready. I did use RSToolbox::mesma() adapting the explanations of [the author](http://remote-sensing.eu/spectral-unmixing-functionality-in-rstoolbox/) and [Dylan Irian @ CAPE RADD](https://www.caperadd.com/news/estimating-kelp-cover-from-landsat-imagery/). The unmixing algorithm itself is comparatively fast and simple as described. Data preperation with terra and the method to select endmembers (!) took a big amount of work which was pretty specific to the study.